# Adding a scrollbar to the eclipse GEF PaletteDrawer

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I'm creating the GEF editor with palette. I added some palette entries to the `PaletteDrawer`. Now I want to show a scrollbar in the `PaletteDrawer`, if there are more palette entries in the `PaletteDrawer`. By default it is showing the small arrows below the `PaletteDrawer`, instead of that, I want right side scrollbar. I searched for few hours, but I didn't get any help.

Answer (score 1):

PaletteViewer has the method [enableVerticalScrollbar()](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.gef.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fgef%2Fui%2Fpalette%2FPaletteViewer.html). If you can contain the PaletteDrawer in a PaletteViewer and set enableVerticalScrollbar(true), it will add a vertical scrollbar on the right.

Unfortunately I can't find any good tutorials or examples (I'm looking for help with GEF myself) to link to.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I already tried this one, It did not worked for me so  I modified the createScrollpane() method in DrawerFigure Class of GEF API. I added the draw2d scrollbar object in createScrollpane() of class DrawerFigure.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I almost give up until i saw your answer, tried it, and worked. As you will see in the method javadoc, This setting must be changed prior to createControl(). But if done so, it works!